# Exclude external javascript content from UIWebView delegate methods

Tags: uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a UIWebview with delegate methods

webViewDidStartLoad
webViewDidFinishLoad

However, on the page I am loading a facebook chat component which for whatever reason is failing to properly load (cache problem? problem with fb?) And it is hitting the server over and over cause my two delegate metods to be called over and over (the only thing they are used for is showing and hiding an activity indicator and therefore I left with a blinking activity indicator)

Is there anyway to stop calling these methods when the page has loaded but is still "trying" to load external content that I do not have control over?

```
  - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@" I am in Webview did start");    

    if ( webView == self.myFlickView )
    {
       [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    }     


}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@" I am in Webview did end");    

    if ( webView == self.myFlickView )
    {
       [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    }     


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delegate to nil at webViewDidFinishLoad. The delegate is probably being called several times due to AJAX calls in the web site loaded. So, use `[webView setDelegate:nil]`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But what happens when they click a link to go to another page there is no longer an activity indicator.